# Set text to website from url

Tags: url, hyperlink, get

I'm trying to do that:

For example, I've got website:

`http://web.com`

and when I enter
`http://web.com/text`

website will be the same but `<h1></h1>` will change to `<h1>text</h1>`

when I enter
`http://web.com/title`

website will be the same but `<h1></h1>` will change to `<h1>title</h1>` etc.

Comment: It don't see you trying anything - so far you only came up with a vague idea.

Comment: You could do something like a querystring or get the url from the response and break it up from there. What have you tried is a bigger question.

Comment: Try using Kelin, it's an awesome PHP router that lets you do stuff like this and it's super simple.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this.
In your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file.html$
RewriteRule .* /file.html [L,R=302]
```

In file.html

```
<h1 id="header">text</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.pathname != "/") {
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML =  window.location.pathname;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Obviously if you don't use .htaccess or it is disabled, you would have to point all requests to file.html some other way.